# Tornado rediret incur TypeError: initialize() missing 1 required positional argument: 'url'

Tags: python-3.x, tornado

I am new to tornado and web service development, and currently implementing a tiny web for practising tornado module.

This is the python code I used for my server

```
import bcrypt
import concurrent.futures
#import MySQLdb
#import markdown
import os.path
import re
import subprocess
#import torndb
import tornado.escape
from tornado import gen
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.options
import tornado.web
import unicodedata
from tornado.options import define, options

define("port",default=8889,help='run on the given port',type=int)


class HomeHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        #login here
        self.render('index.html')

    def post(self):
        def readcodebook(codebook):
            with open(codebook,'r+') as f:
                CodeLines=f.read().split('\n')
                combinations={}
                for c in CodeLines:
                    if len(c)>0:
                        combinations[c.split('\t')[0]]=c.split('\t')[1]
            return combinations
        UserFile='/home/john/PyServer/Users/codebook.txt'
        CodeBook=readcodebook(UserFile)

        if self.get_argument("login") in CodeBook.keys():
            if CodeBook[self.get_argument("login")]==self.get_argument("password"):
                #correct pwd
                self.redirect(self.get_argument("next","/display/"))
            else:
                #incorrect pwd
                self.render("index.html", error='incorrect password!')
                return
        else:
            #user not found
            self.render("index.html", error="account not found!")
            return


class DisplayHandler(tornado.web.RedirectHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render("displaycontent.html")
    pass


class Application(tornado.web.Application):
    def __init__(self):
        handlers = [
            (r"/", HomeHandler),
            (r"/display/", DisplayHandler),
        ]
        settings = dict(
            #blog_title=u"Tornado Blog",
            template_path=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "templates"),
            static_path=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "static"),
            #ui_modules={"Entry": EntryModule},
            #xsrf_cookies=True,
            #cookie_secret="__TODO:_GENERATE_YOUR_OWN_RANDOM_VALUE_HERE__",
            #login_url="/auth/login",
            debug=True,
        )
        tornado.web.Application.__init__(self,handlers,**settings)

if __name__=="__main__":
    tornado.options.parse_command_line()
    http_server=tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(Application())
    http_server.listen(options.port)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

and this is the index.html for user logon:

```
CSSFlow
Login Form
Previous
Next

    Twitter
    Facebook
    RSS
    Newsletter

<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]> <html class="lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]> <html class="lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <title>Login Form</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
  <section class="container">
    <div class="login">
      <h1>Login to Web App</h1>
      <form method="post" action="/">
        <p><input type="text" name="login" value="" placeholder="Username or Email"></p>
        <p><input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password"></p>
        <p class="remember_me">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="remember_me" id="remember_me">
            Remember me on this computer
          </label>
        </p>
        <p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="commit" value="Login"></p>
      </form>
    </div>

    <div class="login-help">
      <p>Forgot your password? <a href="index.html">Click here to reset it</a>.</p>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="about">
    <p class="about-links">
      <a href="http://www.cssflow.com/snippets/login-form" target="_parent">View Article</a>
      <a href="http://www.cssflow.com/snippets/login-form.zip" target="_parent">Download</a>
    </p>
    <p class="about-author">
      &copy; 2012&ndash;2013 <a href="http://thibaut.me" target="_blank">Thibaut Courouble</a> -
      <a href="http://www.cssflow.com/mit-license" target="_blank">MIT License</a><br>
      Original PSD by <a href="http://www.premiumpixels.com/freebies/clean-simple-login-form-psd/" target="_blank">Orman Clark</a>
  </section>
</body>
</html>

    Live Demo
    HTML Source
    SCSS Source

    Tweet
    Share

    View Article
    Download
    Download All

90% Unlimited Downloads Choose from Over 300,000 Vectors, Graphics & Photos.ads via Carbon
```

The problem now is that tornado will throw an uncaught exception with description below and shows Error 404 not found in web browser, when I click submit button in index.html with correct username and password:

```
[E 170108 11:21:55 http1connection:54] Uncaught exception
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/gaobo/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/http1connection.py", line 238, in _read_message
        delegate.finish()
      File "/home/gaobo/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/httpserver.py", line 289, in finish
        self.delegate.finish()
      File "/home/gaobo/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 2022, in finish
        self.execute()
      File "/home/gaobo/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 2042, in execute
        **self.handler_kwargs)
      File "/home/gaobo/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 183, in __init__
        self.initialize(**kwargs)
    TypeError: initialize() missing 1 required positional argument: 'url'
```

Could anybody here point out a way to fix this problem? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tornado offers you two ways to accomplish a redirection. One using the [RedirectHandler](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.RedirectHandler) and the other way using the [redirect](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler.redirect) method of the RequestHandler.

On your example above you mixed these two ways causing the error you get.

On your example, since you use the second way (RequestHandler.redirect), to accomplish a redirection to the `displaycontent.html` on a successful login, you need to replace the parent class of the `DisplayHandler` to be the
`RequestHandler` innstead of the `RedirectHandler`.

eg.

```
class DisplayHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render("displaycontent.html")
```

Also the parameters of the redirect method should only be the url(or alias) you want to redirect to.

eg.

```
#correct pwd
self.redirect("/display/")
```

If you are interested in some more reading for the redirection follow this [link](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/structure.html#redirection).

Comment: Thanks a lot! with parameter changed from tornado.web.RedirectHandler to tornado.web.RequestHandler, my problem can be solved!