# How can I diplay file list in the server with tornado

Tags: web-services, python-3.x, model-view-controller, tornado

I am new to tornado and web service development, and currently implementing a tiny web for practising tornado module.

Based on the web design described in [links here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41529292/tornado-rediret-incur-typeerror-initialize-missing-1-required-positional-argu)

After correct username and password have been submitted, I am trying to display file content of specific folder in the server, and by clicking I can either download a file or enter a subfolder.

Could anybody here tell me the way to implement this function? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is not included in the Tornado project itself. You can implement it yourself using Tornado's API. An example of a project that has done so is here:

https://github.com/hunterlang/Tornado-File-Lister